# Automated Email Service based on Spreadsheet Entry

Tags: java, database

Im looking to create a Java based automatic email service for a group I'm a part of. All the peoples details are currently stored on an excel spreadsheet, and the most important part of that information is their license renew date.

So - if someones license expires next week, the program should automatically send them an email notifying them of when it expires and what to do next.

I take it it would be best to export the database to the Java equivalent or does it matter?

Any tips on how to start would be great.

Thanks

Comment: have you started writing your codes?

Comment: Well a Database would be a sensible step to take, but you could also read from the spreadsheet file with Apache POI.

Comment: @Kent have started creating a dummy database - don't want to touch the real think at the momment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Process Excel spreadsheet using either

**Apache POI** http://poi.apache.org/ or **Jexcel**

then use **Javamail** http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

for sending mail

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple application (web or standalone) that uses http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ to read in the Excel sheet, then fire off an email once you have processed the appropriate field (and a flag is raised)?

This would avoid you having to convert the Excel into a different database. Size may be an issue (but you don't state), and you don't state how often you want this to run.

Hope this helps